# How Can I refer To A Document in Firestore from Flutter And Get That Data In A Different Place In The App

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection 'products' inside which i have documents for each product with field 'category' now I want to refer to document of specific category from separate Top Level collections "categories",in in this field 'category', in the firebase console I can simply select the document that I want to point to, I want to know how to do this in my flutter app programatically and how to retrieve this data inside the same app in a different place, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a `FutureBuilder` or a `StreamBuilder` to retrieve the data like so:

```
FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  future: Firestore.instance.collection("products").getDocuments(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.data != null)
      return Text("No data!");
    else
      return Text(snapshot.data.documents[0].category);
  },
)
```

Use `.snapshot()` for a stream. Both return documents as a List, so sort them beforehand.
Using something like `.orderBy()`. Then refer with an index.